# Python `is_trait_type` doesn't work with `Date`

Tags: python, date, traits

In the project I work for, we often need to convert text to the value of a trait. Generally, we use the `is_trait_type` method to do the appropriate conversion.

However, it doesn't work with `Date` traits. Here is a MWE:

```
from traits.has_traits import HasTraits
from traits.trait_types import Int, Date

class A(HasTraits):
    a_date = Date
    an_int = Int

a = A()
class_traits = a.class_traits()
print class_traits["an_int"].is_trait_type(Int)
print class_traits["a_date"].is_trait_type(Date)
```

The `Int` behave as expected but the `Date` fails with:

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

We use Enthought `traits` module (version 4.1.0) under Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What `traits` module is this? The Enthought thing, the PEAK thing, or something else?

Comment: Date is a `traits.trait_types.BaseInstance object` as opposed to a  `<class 'traits.trait_types.Int'>` so you need  `.__class__` for Date

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Isn't `Date.__class__` just going to be `traits.trait_type.BaseInstance`? It seems like checking against that either isn't going to work, or is going to treat all `BaseInstance`-type type traits as equivalent, neither of which seems that useful.

Comment: @abarnert, Yes youare right.  I don't see Date used anywhere in the docs with `is_trait_type`  either.

Comment: Date is not created like the other types, it is created using BaseInstance and datetime.date  `Date = BaseInstance(datetime.date, editor=date_editor)`

Comment: Well, the docs for [`trait_types.Date`](http://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_api_reference/trait_types.html#traits.trait_types.Date) don't seem very enlightening… Is it possible that this is a bug in the way `BaseInstance`-derived traits work in the current version? I don't know enough about this library to know how this is _supposed_ to work, and I don't want to go digging through the source to guess…

Comment: @Mathieu Dubios, are you meant to create a trait in the class like `a_int = Int(1)`?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but what can I do now? Is that a bug?

@ Padraic Cunningham: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `Date` (and `Time`) trait types are not classes but instances. The `is_trait_type(x)` method checks whether `self.trait_type` is an instance of the provided class (i.e. the value of `x`), and hence it fails if `x` is not a class. In my opinion, this a bug in the API.

If you need a workaround, you can define a method like this:

```
def my_is_trait_type(trait, trait_type):
    if isinstance(trait_type, BaseInstance):
        return trait.is_trait_type(trait_type.__class__)
    else:
        return trait.is_trait_type(trait_type)
```

However, I would reconsider using `is_trait_type()` for the task of finding the appropriate conversion. Maybe a map would do, for instance.