# How to restrict values in a Float trait in Enthought traits module?

Tags: python, validation, enthought, traits

I'm a bit new to Enthought `traits` module. I would like to specify a trait for which only a few floating-point values are allowed. Unfortunately, I can't use a `Enum` because it breaks the code base I'm working on. How can I specify which values are valid for a `Float`? Do I have to create another class deriving from `Float` with an overloaded `validate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `traits` docs indicate that you should subclass the `Float` trait and add your custom validation code.

See the section about [Custom Traits](http://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_user_manual/custom.html). I'd take a look at the source for the implementation of `Enum` as well.

Comment: Thanks! After re-thinking about it I think subclassing could also break the existing code so I will simply ignore the constraints for now but I keep this answer in mind.

Comment: Would you accept or upvote the answer if it was useful to you? Also, I'm curious to know how does the code break if you use an `Enum` or `Float` subclass? To me, it seems like an `Enum` should fit your spec very well.

Comment: Answer accepted. I think that the code might break because the objects are stored in a DB. Therefore many operations depends on the type of each traits. `is_trait_type` would probably recognize the subclass as a `Float` but I'm not sure it's used consistently (it's a prototype) and `is_trait_type` doesn't work for some types (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671969/python-is-trait-type-doesnt-work-with-date)). For `Enum`, it breaks because we store the values as strings (we didn't realize that `traits` `Enum` can contain heterogeneous values).

Comment: I see. Then maybe I would prefer subclassing `Enum` to convert the values into floats before storing/validating. Anyway, I'm glad if I could be to some assistance.